# Better way of calculating values for rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate values for rows in a data frame.
Basically I have a data frame which contains 5 columns with either 0 or 1 (presence/absence). I want to randomize the order of those values over those 5 columns, apply a calculation to those columns, replicate this a 1000 times, then calculate the mean of the different calculation per column and then sum those values into one value per row.

I tried doing this with lapply and apply but got nowhere somehow. I managed to do it with a for loop, but I wonder if there is a shorter/nicer way of doing it.

This is what I ended up with and works as needed:

```
> df <- data.frame(t(replicate(10,sample(c(0,1),5,replace=TRUE))))
> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   1  1  0  1  1
2   1  1  1  0  0
3   0  0  0  1  0
4   0  1  1  1  0
5   0  0  1  0  1
6   0  1  1  1  0
7   0  0  1  0  1
8   0  0  0  0  1
9   1  0  0  1  0
10  0  1  0  1  1
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
+   v<-sum(
+     rowMeans(
+       replicate(1000,{
+         sample(as.numeric(df[i,c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")]),5, replace=FALSE)*c(5,4,3,2,1)
+       }
+       )
+     )
+   )
+   df[i,c("tot")]<-v
+ }
> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5     tot
1   1  1  0  1  1 12.0184
2   1  1  1  0  0  8.9786
3   0  0  0  1  0  3.0138
4   0  1  1  1  0  9.0013
5   0  0  1  0  1  6.0196
6   0  1  1  1  0  9.0227
7   0  0  1  0  1  5.9837
8   0  0  0  0  1  3.0063
9   1  0  0  1  0  6.0069
10  0  1  0  1  1  9.0032
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
df$tot <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  sum(
    rowMeans(
       replicate(
         1000, sample(x, 5, replace=F)*5:1
       )
    )
 )
})
```

Comment: THis is great. I don't know why I couldn't get it to work. I guess there are so many ways of doing things with all the apply family of functions I stopped seeing the obvious. One more question though, is there a way to do this with lapply, because then I could leverage multicore with mclapply.

Comment: .. like `lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(x) {...`? Sadly, I never got multicore things to work on my PC.

Comment: Awesome, that works as well. Now on to the multicore challenge :).

Comment: A bit off topic now, but I just included the parallel package and subsituted lapply for mclapply and it worked. I could see two cores going to 100% use instead of one before, and the results were much much faster there.